# Key Listener not working?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keylistener

I have some java code and I got my program working but I wanted to add some key shortcuts. For some reason I cannot get this to work. It has the same code as a button on the program and when I hit the button it works , but when I try hitting the enter key it's not working . Any suggestions?

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        try{
        al.add(Integer.parseInt(txtGrade.getText()));
        txtGrade.setText("");
        txtGrade.requestFocus();
        numOfGrades++;
        lblGRecord.setText(numOfGrades + " Grades Recorded");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a number");
            txtGrade.selectAll();
            txtGrade.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add a KeyListener to a JTextField and trying to capture the Enter key press. If so don't. Instead just give the JTextField an ActionListener which will do the same thing but will actually work.

e.g.,

```
txtGrade.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try{
        al.add(Integer.parseInt(txtGrade.getText()));
        txtGrade.setText("");
        numOfGrades++;
        lblGRecord.setText(numOfGrades + " Grades Recorded");
    } catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a number");
        txtGrade.selectAll();
    }
    txtGrade.requestFocusInWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Ok, but like I said I have it so that my button works for it, but I want it to work with a key . What can I add to that code to make it work with the enter key?

Comment: @Kalkrin: I've just shown you. Please look carefully -- I'm adding the ActionListener to the **JTextField** ***NOT*** the JButton. Alternatively, you could simplify things and add the same ActionListener (or Action) to both.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I see how it works now. What if I wanted to make it a letter key like r for example and make it so that in my JButton, the r in "record" was underlined.

Comment: @Kalkrin: JButton (actually its parent, AbstractButton) has a method, `setMnemonic(...)` that can help. Check out the [AbstractButton API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic(int)) for the details on this.

Comment: @Kalkrin: i.e, `myButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);`

Comment: @nachokk: yep, and that's how most mnemonics are supposed to work.

Comment: @Kalkrin: if you want to capture the `r` key without it being `alt-r`, then you will want to look into using Key Bindings.

Comment: That is what i was wanting you to say ;) `KeyBindings` :D